# Add an Existing Field Update to an Existing Workflow Rule

Tags: workflow, field-update

I created a Field Update.  I also created a Workflow Rule.  I want to add the existing Field Update to the existing Workflow Rule, but there's only an option to create a New Field Update:

[image]

If I click "New Field Update", I have to create the Field Update on the spot.  How do you add an existing one?  I just want to save some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option at the last in your screenshot that says "Select Existing Action" .That should get you option to add existing .